# How to remove files with given extension from Git history except when a tag exists for the commit

Tags: git

Is there a way to delete **one file** or **all files with a given extension** from the history of a Git repository? But except if there's a tag on the commit.

So rewrite the history, remove the file or files with extension BUT don't touch commits with a tag on it.

I've checked BFG but that will just go and clean all occurences.

Comment: If you want to preserve all tags it's not enough to don't touch commits with a tag on it. You must not touch any commit between tags too. The bottom line: if you want to preserve tags you can only rewrite history between the last tag and the HEAD.

Comment: I don't know of a built in way in rewriting tools to do this (`git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo` - not exactly built in, but promoted as the standard replacement for `filter-branch`). If I had to do it, I would look into the details of how to execute a custom script on each rewriting step with one of these tools.